# How can I run an example from a Flutter package/library?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have the following simple directory structure:

```
flutter_published
    .idea
    android
    build
    ios
    lib
        main.dart 
    flutter_published.iml
    pubspec.lock
    pubspec.yaml
    network_to_file_image
        .idea
        example
            main.dart 
        lib
            network_to_file_image.dart
        test
        network_to_file_image.iml
        pubspec.lock
        pubspec.yaml
```

`network_to_file_image` is a package.

There are two `main.dart files`, one at `flutter_published/lib/main.dart` and 
another at `flutter_published/network_to_file_image/example/main.dart`

I am able to run the first one, but not the one inside of the `example` directory under `network_to_file_image`. The second one gives me this error:

```
   Launching example\lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
   No application found for TargetPlatform.android_x86.
   Is your project missing an android\AndroidManifest.xml?
   Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

Also, when the app is generated, what happens to the `example` and `test` directories of the packages I use? Are they included or removed from the final app that is deployed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve this, instead of the `main.dart` file inside of the `example` directory, you need to create a complete Flutter application-type project inside of the `example` directory. Then, the example tab will point to the `README.md` file inside of that directory.

That `example` directory will have its own `lib` directory, containing a `main.dart` file. Since that file is now inside of an application-type directory it can be run.

Visit this repo to see how it works:

https://github.com/marcglasberg/async_redux/tree/master/example

---

**Update:**

To be clear, the example's `pubspec.yaml` file can reference its package by using a relative reference. For example, here is the `dependencies` section of the `example` dir of the `async_redux` package I mentioned:

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.13.1
  async_redux:
    path: ../
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

Since the `example` dir is at the same level as the package's `pubspec.yaml` file, then the example's own `pubspec.yaml` is one level below it. Thus, it may reference the package itself by using a `../` path:

```
  async_redux:
    path: ../
```

Comment: How would I "create a complete Flutter application-type project inside of the example directory", using the `main()` already provided? I run `flutter create` in there, or...?

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård Just create the Flutter app project, and put your `main.dart` file there.

Comment: Ok, that's definitely not true. I need to put EVERYTHING from the example folder there, not just the `main.dart`. I did that, replacing all files having the same name, and yeah, it built... I still suspect there must be a less roundabout way to do it, though! One which doesn't involve creating lots of files which I'm just going to replace...

Comment: Yes, of course I meant everything from the example in there. Usually the example is just a single main.dart file, but if you break it into more files then you have to put all of them there. But your package itself (that the example is using) you don´t need to put in there. You just reference it from your example´s pubspec.yaml. I am going to update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`example/main.dart` only exists to be shown in https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/network_to_file_image#-example-tab-

The pub site is limited in how it finds content in the example directory to display in the `Example` tab.

Comment: So when you are developing the package you actually need to create the example somewhere else and then just copy it there?

Comment: Yes, copy it to example do it will be shown on the web page. There were some discussions in issues about that, but couldn't find them.

Answer (score 1):

cd to the directory and execute `flutter create .`. You should be able to run it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the `example folder` of the repository of the package.
2. Open the `lib folder` and go to the `main.dart` file.
3. Above the `void main()` function, you can see the `Run|Debug|Profile` (pic below), click on the one you want to run the project as.

[image]

4. The example app will now run in your emulator.

The screenshot below is of the `chewie package` available on `pub.dev`